# Finding elements using Ranorex spy is inconsistent

Tags: python, automation, ui-automation, ui-testing, ranorex

Ranorex 10 version is used.

For tests with the exact work flow, ranorex spy is sometimes able to find the element and the other times it only keeps searching and the script gets timed out.

Tried providing the whole path instead of just the automation id, it didn't work.

Can anything else be done?

Comment: could you please share code or something to elaborate on your problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to test a desktop app or a webbrowser app?
Without further information it is difficult to examine the problem, unfortunately.

But it can be helpful checking following things:

1. For a webbrowser app, please check the ranorex browser extension
2. please check your root path (of the element). maybe for some reasons it changes from time to time and the element cannot be found. Try to make the path more unspecific
3. Check your whitelist in ranorex